# AWS Neptune import data from S3 invalid import task role

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam, amazon-neptune

I have an AWS Neptune cluster with 1 instance. I want to create a new graph by importing data (gremlin format) from a csv file of an S3 bucket. I try to perform this action via the management console UI. The operation fails with the following error:
**"Error creating Analytics Graph my_graph.
Invalid import task role - [arn:aws:iam:::role/<role_name>]. Please check the permissions and trust policy associated with the role."**

To be sure that the permissions are sufficient I asssigned the predefined Admin policy to the role. The trust policy is the following:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "rds.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

I created a VPC gateway endpoint as described here: [Creating the Amazon S3 VPC Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/neptune/latest/userguide/bulk-load-tutorial-vpc.html)
I have assigned the role used for the import task to the neptune cluster.

I Tried turning the IAM authentication on the cluster on and off. I tried making the S3 bucket public as well as enabling ACLs. None of those changes made any difference regarding the error message.

Comment: Are you trying to create a Neptune Database cluster or a Neptune Analytics cluster?  The Import Graph API is for Neptune Analytics.

Comment: Maybe you're right and I used the wrong functionality. I was now able to import my data by creating an EC2 instance in the private VPC from the neptune cluster and calling the neptune loader api endpoint from EC2. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Awesome!  Well done.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue and was eventually able to start an import task with the following trust policy (`neptune-graph.amazonaws.com` instead of `rds.amazonaws.com`)

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "Service": "neptune-graph.amazonaws.com"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
    ]
}
```